# How to store order data from shopify webhooks in mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, shopify, webhooks

I want to use shopify order webhook to store order data into mysql database. I am beginner in webhooks. Googled many times to find the guidance about how to achieve it.I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652801/shopify-order-create-webhook-inserting-into-mysql-using-php) solutions is very close for me.I wrote the php code but I am getting error like this [error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqyHz.jpg).I don't know why I am getting this error and how to resolve it.Please suggest us.

I followed these steps

1. I created the webhook from shopify admin dashboard
2. Point the webhook to my own domain
3. And write the following code in the pointed link
   here is my code

my code is

```
<?php
$webhook_content = NULL;

 // Get webhook content from the POST
 $webhook = fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
 while (!feof($webhook)) {
 $webhook_content .= fread($webhook, 4096);
 }

 fclose($webhook);

 // Decode Shopify POST
 $webhook_content = json_decode($webhook_content, TRUE);

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "xxxxxxxx_xxxhalis"; 
$username = "xxxxxxxx_xxxhalis";
$password = "***********";
$sql = "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database;";

 // Create a new connection to the MySQL database using PDO, $my_Db_Connection is an object
 try { 
  $db = new PDO($sql, $username, $password);
  //echo "<p> DB Connect = Success.</p>";
 } catch (PDOException $error) {
  echo 'Connection error: ' . $error->getMessage();
 }
    $order_num= $webhook_content['name'];
    $order_date = $webhook_content['created_at'];
    $order_mode = "Online";
    $location= $webhook_content['default_address']['province'];
    $cust_name = $webhook_content['billing_address']['name'];
    $address = $webhook_content['default_address']['address1']['address2']['city']['province']['zip'];
    $phone_num = $webhook_content['default_address']['phone'];
    
    $special_note= $webhook_content['note'];
    $total_mrp = $webhook_content['current_subtotal_price'];
    $total_discount= $webhook_content['current_total_discounts'];
    $sub_total = $webhook_content['current_subtotal_price'];
    $delivery_charges = $webhook_content['presentment_money']['amount'];
    
    $totalOrderValues= $webhook_content['total_price'];
    $discount_approval = "NA";
    $invoice_status= "NA";
    $punching_status = "NA";
    $order_source = "Shopify";
    
    $payment_mode= $webhook_content['payment_gateway_names'];
    $payement_status = "Done";
    $payement_recieve_date= $webhook_content['processed_at'];
    $reference_number = $webhook_content['reference'];
    $cash_handover_status = "NA";

$my_Insert_Statement = $my_Db_Connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `customer_order_sab`( `order_num`, `order_datetime`, `modeOfOrder`, `location`, `customer_name`, `address`, `phone_number`, `special_note`, `total_mrp`, `total_discount`, `sub_total`, `delivery_charges`, `totalOrderValues`, `discount_approval`, `invoice_status`, `punching_status`, `order_source`, `payment_mode`, `payement_status`, `payement_recieve_date`, `reference_number`, `cash_handover_status`) VALUES (:order_num, :order_date, :order_mode, :location, :cust_name, :address, :phone_num, :special_note, :total_mrp, :total_discount, :sub_total, :delivery_charges, :totalOrderValues, :discount_approval, :invoice_status, :punching_status, :order_source, :payment_mode, :payement_status, :payement_recieve_date, :reference_number, :cash_handover_status)");

$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':order_num', $order_num);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':order_date', $order_date);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':order_mode', $order_mode);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':location', $location);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':cust_name', $cust_name);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':address', $address);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':phone_num', $phone_num);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':special_note', $special_note);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':total_mrp', $total_mrp);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':total_discount', $total_discount);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':sub_total', $sub_total);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':delivery_charges', $delivery_charges);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':totalOrderValues', $totalOrderValues);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':discount_approval', $discount_approval);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':invoice_status', $invoice_status);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':punching_status', $punching_status);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':order_source', $order_source);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':payment_mode', $payment_mode);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':payement_status', $payement_status);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':payement_recieve_date', $payement_recieve_date);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':reference_number', $reference_number);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(':cash_handover_status', $cash_handover_status);
if ($my_Insert_Statement->execute()) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Unable to create record";
}



?>
```

Comment: The error messages mean, that `$webhook_content` is Null. So you'll have to do a bit of debugging and figure out why. Either your while loop there did not actually populate it with any JSON to decode afterwards - or decoding the JSON went wrong.

Comment: That while loop should not be necessary, you should be able to get the request body using just `file_get_contents('php://input')`

Comment: after removing the while loop and adding file_get_contents('php://input') it's showing another error     Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home/*****/domains/******.com/public_html/shopify/index.php on line 6

Comment: I meant remove the whole thing, including what you are doing _inside_ the loop. And the fopen/fclose. The one line I showed you is all you need to get the request body content.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong in one giant respect, but I respect you for trying!

If you expect webhooks to be sent to your App from some store where you installed your App, and you expect to save data from the webhooks in your database you cannot create the webhooks from the Shopify Admin and then process them in your App due to security. Instead, you install a webhook from your App, instructing Shopify to send your App webhooks. This way, Shopify can use your App API token to secure the webhooks. Your App then receives webhooks and decides if they are legit or not. You cannot do that if you use the Admin.

Read up on creating webhooks for use with your App! You can choose RestAPI or GraphQL and go from there.